# Automate seekbar selection on Android UI using Appium pytest (needs CodeSample)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, pytest, appium

Needs a sample Selenium python code, which illustrate seekbar selection up/down based on specific values in range min to max.

web source:

```
<android.view.View resource-id="">
    <android.widget.SeekBar content-desc="8" resource-id="">
```

Really appreciate for any added inputs, UI looks and feel are as below screen:

[image]